# Check that an array contains only numbers

Tags: c, arrays

I'm having a problem where I am wanting to go through an array and check that only positive numbers have been entered. I know that it is possible to use isDigit from ctype.h but I'd rather construct something myself. The way I think it is possible, is to iterate through each element of the array and see if the value stored there is between 0 and 9, but it isn't working. This is my code so far:

```
char testArray[11] = {'0'};  
printf("Enter a string no longer than 10 chars");  
scanf("%s", testArray);  
int x;  
int notanumber = 0;  
for (x = 0; x < 11; x++) {  
        if ((testArray[x] < 0) || (testArray[x] > 9)) {  
                notanumber++;  
        }  
}  
printf("%i", notanumber);
```

Comment: `'0'` is a `char` representing `0` it's not the number/numeric value `0`.

Comment: Iterate over array and add it's elements. Every consecutive sum must be higher that previous.

Comment: There is a standard function to check if a character is a digit: `isdigit`

Comment: You're really better off using `isdigit` for this operation.  It protects you from a number of encoding issues that can bite you if you aren't careful.

Comment: Not sure why this was edited to have gibberish in it, but please change it back!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not working because `0` and `9` are integers not characters.
Change your `if` condition to

```
if((testArray[x] >= '0') || (testArray[x] <= '9')){ ... }
```

to check the digits from 0 to 9.

Comment: Thank you, I always slip up on remembering to include '' around char values.

Answer (score 0):

this line

```
if((testArray[x] < 0) || (testArray[x] > 9)){
```

should be replaced by

```
if((testArray[x] < '0') || (testArray[x] > '9')){
```